# onchange in select tag with jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, onchange

I tried to search something similar but I failed, so, I'm asking here
this is a piece of my code:

```
<div id="ui-widget">
<label>Doc Type: </label>
        <select id="classes" onchange="createForm()">
            <option value=" ">Select a type ... </option>
                <#list typenames?keys as key>
                        <#if typenames[key]!="">
                        <option value="${key}">${typenames[key]}</option>
                                                    </#if>
                </#list>
        </select>

    </div>
```

the `select` tag is using this jQuery:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox
with autocomplete;

The function `createForm()` is a Javascript that creates different form depending on which selection you make in the select tag;
But using autocomplete from jQuery, the `onchange` event in the `select` tag seems not working.
Is there a method to inject some JavaScript code like my function to work on selection change of this jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following to bind the `autocompleteselect` event for the autocomplete :

```
$( "#classes" ).autocomplete({
   select: createForm
});
```

or

```
$( "#classes" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) { 
        // your code here 
   }
});
```

or

```
$( "#classes" ).bind( "autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {
  // your code here
});
```

[Docs are here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select)

Comment: Nice one, I'm almost done, now I have to change a little bit of JavaScript code that is not working properly, but at least the function is called on selection.
One thing more, I have to select two times the same value in the selection field for function to be called properly, otherwise it calls the last one. 
I'll try to explain it better:

I open the web page with the code
I try to make a selection
nothing happens
try to make the same selection
the function is called back
I try to call a different selection
the function is called with the previous selection
and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to bind it to the autocomplete event `autocompleteselect`